# Can we check which property fails validation in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor component that holds a form input and some extra markup. Thanks to some excellent help from @enet (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227405/706346)) I now have it so that if the validation on the model property fails, the `<ValidationMessage>` correctly displays the message.

However, I would like to have this `<ValidationMessage>` tag surrounded by HTML that only appears when the validation message is shown, ie when validation fails for that property. I can do that by introducing a private `bool`, and using it as follows...

```
    @if (_showValidationMsg) {
      <div class="input-group-append"><label class="input-group-text has-error" for="@PropertyName">
        <ValidationMessage For="@ValueExpression" /></label>
      </div>
    }

@code {
  // other stuff here as well

  private bool _showValidationMsg = false;

  private async Task OnChanged(ChangeEventArgs cea) {
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(cea.Value?.ToString() ?? "");
    FieldIdentifier identifier = CascadedEditContext.Field(PropertyName);
    CascadedEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(identifier);
    _showValidationMsg = !CascadedEditContext.Validate();
  }

}
```

This works fine when the component only has one input element, but one of my components has two input controls, and I would like to know which one has failed validation, so I can show/hide the correct bit of HTML.

Is there a way of finding out which model properties failed validation?

Comment: Shalom, do you realize that as long as the OnChanged method is not fired, the ValidationMessage remains invisible though it should be displayed with the message that asks the user to enter a value. This occurs when you click on the "Save" button without entering values to the fields.  I'll try to think of a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have called `CascadedEditContext.Validate` (you can ignore the result as you don't need it, see below), you can then use `GetValidationMessages` to get the validation messages for the property. If there aren't any, it passed validation.

Using your code as a base, you could wrap this into a reusable method as follows...

```
private async Task<bool> CheckValidationFor(ChangeEventArgs cea, EventCallback<string> valueChangedEventCallback, string propertyName) {
  await valueChangedEventCallback.InvokeAsync(cea.Value?.ToString() ?? "");
  FieldIdentifier identifier = CascadedEditContext.Field(propertyName);
  CascadedEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(identifier);
  CascadedEditContext.Validate();
  return CascadedEditContext.GetValidationMessages(identifier).Any();
```

}

You could then simplify your `OnChanged1` code to this...

```
private async Task OnChanged1(ChangeEventArgs cea) =>
  _showValidationMsg1 = await CheckValidationFor(cea, Value1Changed, PropertyName1);
```

Likewise for `OnChanged2`

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant!